# Azure PowerShell Connect-AzureAD and Connect-MsolService both with MFA connect

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

i use a script to connect AzureAD and MsolService.

```
Connect-AzureAD
Connect-MsolService
```

and it ask me both for username, password, and telephone verification.

Is there a way to only enter the information once ?

Comment: I can't say that I know the answer to the question. However, if you just query the graph directly with a certificate or secret based authentication, you would not need MFA. The graph has all the information you would need with one authentication token. I do have to admit that is it not as intuitive as using commands from the two modules you are referencing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using graph like @AdminofThings said, then you will be prompted with MFA (Password + telephone verification) every time you connect to a service. Since you are connecting to 2 services MSOL and Azure it will prompt you for MFA twice.

Answer (score -1):

If the credentials are the same:

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential
Connect-MsolService -Credential $Credential
```

As per:

[Microsoft Docs | Connect-AzureAD Examples](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread?view=azureadps-2.0#example-2-connect-a-session-using-a-variable)

and

[Microsoft Docs | Connect-MsolService Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/connect-msolservice?view=azureadps-1.0)